# What is difference between page with session_destroy() and without

Tags: php, session

Is it right way that session_start() and [session_destroy();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) be in the same page?

```
session_start();
page content
session_destroy();
```

Comment: title and body asking two different questions

Comment: @experimentX , I guess so dummy! Our developer has added both start and destroy session in hight traffic page!!

Comment: well, it's like you make a boat, burn it, and swim across the river.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of sessions is to be available across multiple requests. If you destroy a session with `session_destroy()`, the session will not be available anymore. So, usually, you will not call `session_destroy()` on any page unless you want to completely end it, like in a "logout" functionality.

If you do want to destroy the session, you must call `session_start()` to open the session before you can destroy it with `session_destroy()`.